# Converting Multibyte characters to UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, multibyte

My application has to write data to an XML file which will be read by a swf file. The swf expects the data in the XML to be in UTF-8 encoding. I have to convert some Multibyte characters in my app(Chinese simplified, Japanese, Korean etc..) to UTF-8. 
      Are there any API calls which could allow me to do this?I would prefer not to use any 3rd party dlls. I need to do it both on Windows and on Mac and would prefer any system API's if available.

Thanks
jbsp72

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding (Well, a variable byte-length encoding to be precise). Stating that you need to convert from a multibyte encoding is not enough. You need to specify *which* multibye encoding your source is?

Comment: Also, please specify the environment/language you need this for.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to convert some Multibyte
>   characters in my app(Chinese
>   simplified, Japanese, Korean etc..) to
>   UTF-8.

if your original string is in multibyte (chinese/arabic/thai/etc..) and you need to convert it to other multibyte (UTF-8), One way is to convert to WideCharacter(UTF-16) first, then convert back to multibyte.

```
multibyte(chinese/arabic/thai/etc) -> widechar(UTF-16) -> multibyte(UTF-8)
```

if your original string is already in Unicode(UTF-16), you can skip the first conversion in the above illustration

you can refer the codepage from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756(VS.85).aspx).

Google Chrome has some string conversion implementations for Windows, Linux, and Mac. You can see it [here](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/?dir_pagestart=300) or [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#YwaaF8DorRY/src/base/sys_string_conversions.h&q=widechar%20chrome%20package:%22git://github.com/kesor/chromium.git%22&d=2). the files are under src/base:
+ [sys_string_conversions.h](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/sys_string_conversions.h?view=markup)
+ [sys_string_conversions_linux.cc](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/sys_string_conversions_linux.cc)
+ [sys_string_conversions_win.cc](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/sys_string_conversions_win.cc?view=markup)
+ [sys_string_conversions_mac.mm](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/sys_string_conversions_mac.mm)

The code uses BSD license so you can use it for commercial projects.